# `ClassCastException` when case object with `ScriptEngine`

Tags: java, groovy, scriptengine

I try to pass object between Java and Groovy with `ScriptEngine` so that I can decouple some logic into groovy script. But I met two problems:

1. cannot pass object to groovy script.
2. cannot obtain object from groovy script.

Here are the codes:

App.java

```
package test.testScriptEngine;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;

import javax.script.Bindings;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;


public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        App app=new App();
        Output out=app.runSript();
        System.out.println(out.a);
    }

    public Output runSript() throws ScriptException, FileNotFoundException {

        ScriptEngineManager sem = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = sem.getEngineByName("groovy");
        Bindings binding = engine.createBindings();

        Input input=new Input(4,5);
        binding.put("input", input);

        FileReader reader = new FileReader("src/main/resources/test.groovy");
        Object obj = engine.eval(reader, binding);

        return (Output) obj;
    }

}
class Input{
    public Input(int i, int j) {
        this.a=i;
        this.b=j;
    }
    int a=1;
    int b=2;
}
class Output{
    int a=1;
}
```

test.groovy

```
package test.testScriptEngine;

class Input{
        int a=1;
        int b=2;
    Input(int a,int b){
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
    }
}
class Output{
        int a=1;
}

Output cal(Input input){
    Output out= new Output();
    out.a=input.a+input.b;
    println(out.a);
    return out;
}
Input input=new Input(2,3);
return cal(input);
```

Output are:

```
5
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: test.testScriptEngine.Output cannot be cast to test.testScriptEngine.Output
    at test.testScriptEngine.App.runSript(App.java:31)
    at test.testScriptEngine.App.main(App.java:15)
```

Expected output should be `9` and `Output` should be returned.

Comment: Usually, a CCE saying "X cannot be cast to X" indicates a ClassLoader problem, where you have two different classloaders involved, so the two instances are not the same even though they have the same class name.  In this case I'm not sure that applies, but I can't think of another good reason for the error.  Double-check that Groovy doesn't have its own classloader hierarchy.

Comment: Right! I will check that. If that true, how should I solve this problem? Or must I exchange data in string(json format maybe) instead of object?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Groovy at all.  If you do a Google search on "groovy classloading" you get lots of "interesting" hits discussing how to modify classloading, so it looks like this is a known issue.  I suggest you work your way though the Google results to see if you can find a solution.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I'm almost positive that the instance created by the Groovy code is NOT the same class as the one created by the Java code.  Groovy probably creates its class and instance of `Output` dynamically at runtime.

Comment: @JimGarrison I will try to find a solution to fix this problem :) thanks for your hit.

Comment: If you solve the problem, please come back here and write up your solution _as an answer_, and then "accept" the answer after the required delay.  It will help future searchers with the same problem.

Comment: `App.java` is not a valid java file : it defines classes 'Input' and 'Output' but not as nested classes. Where are these classes really defined ?

Comment: Also, you seem to be declaring classes in Java and groovy, then expecting these to be passed happily around... You have two classes called input and two called output this can't be right

Comment: @JérémieB this is allowed in java. You can try it.

Answer (score 1):

When the Groovy class loader compiles your script it creates the class `test.testScriptEngine.Output`.

However, the class generated from the script is not the same as the `test.testScriptEngine.Output` class compiled from the Java code. Even if their bytecode would be equal, the different class loaders would make them different classes.

Comment: Or to help him a bit further: Delete the classes from the script, so they are only defined in java.. They would still be accessible from the script.